# a problem with pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have never been good at playing with pointers in C. But this time I would like to ask for your help to resolve my problems with pointers. 
I have a function here to push a value into a stack.

```
void StackPush(stackT *stackPtr, stackElementT element){

 stackNodeT* node = (stackNodeT *) malloc(sizeof(stackNodeT));  

 if (node == NULL){
  fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed\n");
  exit(1);
 } else {                                   
  node->element = element;
  node->next = StackEmpty(stackPtr)? NULL : *stackPtr; 
  *stackPtr = node;
 }
}
```

If I change the last line to stackPtr = &node; this function does not work. My question is why? What's the difference between *stackPtr = node; and stackPtr = &node; ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stackT *stackPtr` defines stackPtr as a pointer to `stackT`. The caller of the function passes a `stackT` object to this function.

Now, `*stackPtr = node;` modifies the value pointed to by the pointer `stackPtr` whereas `stackPtr = &node;` modifies the local value of the pointer variable itself.

```
stackT *mystack = createStack();
//mystack points to an empty stack

StackPush1(mystack, elem1);//stackpush1 uses *stackPtr = node;
//mystack points to the node with elem1

StackPush2(mystack, elem2);//stackpush2 uses stackPtr = &node;
//the function updates its local copy, not the passed variable
//mystack still points to the elem1
//node with elem2 is not accessible and is a memory leak.
```

---

> lets say we have int k=4; if I enter something like *ptr = k; in the "main" body (not inside a function), the results should be the same as ptr = &k;?

Not exactly. Run the following code and see the difference for yourself:

```
int k = 4;
//declare a pointer to int and initialize it
int *ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
//now ptr1 contains the address of a memory location in heap

//store the current value into the address pointed to by ptr1
*ptr1 = k; /* this line will fail if we hadn't malloced 
              in the previous line as it would try to 
              write to some random location */

//declare a pointer to int 
int *ptr2;
//and assign address of k to it
ptr2 = &k;

printf("Before \n*ptr1 = %d *ptr2 = %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);
//change the value of k
k = 5;
printf("After  \n*ptr1 = %d *ptr2 = %d\n", *ptr1, *ptr2);
```

Post a comment if you need more clarification.

Comment: lets say we have int k=4; if I enter something like *ptr = k; in the "main" body (not inside a function), the results should be the same as ptr = &k; ?

Answer (score 2):

```
*stackPtr = node;
```

This dereferences `stackPtr` and sets the object pointed at to the value of `node`.

```
stackPtr = &node;
```

This changes the pointer `stackPtr` to point to the `node` pointer which is allocated on the stack.

Basically, in the first case, you are changing the thing that the pointer refers to (called the *referent* of the pointer) but the pointer itself remains unchanged.  In the second case, you are changing the pointer to refer to something different.

Answer (score 1):

Once `stackPtr` is passed in (by value), it is a local (automatic) variable, and modifying it doesn't affect any of the caller's automatic variables.  However, when you do:

```
*stackPtr = node;
```

you're modifying the object it *points* to.

Answer (score 0):

*stackPtr = node

makes stackPtr point to what you've malloc'd.

*stackPtr = &node

makes stackPtr point to the address of a local variable, which will most likely be invalid once you return from this function.